# EF relationship adds new record instead of linking

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I know you'll tell me this has been asked before. Maybe I don't search correctly, but I don't find the answer.

```
var userRepo = new UserRepository();
var user = new User {Name = "Bob"};
userRepo.Save(user);

var roleRepo = new RoleRepository();
var role = new Role {Name = "My role"};
roleRepo.Save(role);

user.Roles.Add(role); //I expect this to link user to role, but it adds a second role
userRepo.Save(user);
```

Maybe the problem is in my repository, but I doubt:

```
public void Save(Role role)
{
    if (role.ID == 0)
         context.Roles.Add(role);
    else
    {
         var currentRole = context.Roles.Find(role.ID);
         context.Entry(currentRole).CurrentValues.SetValues(role);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();

 }
```

Comment: While searching you must have read that `DbSet.Add` changes the state of the whole object graph into `Added`.

Comment: @GertArnold Then what should replace the line user.Roles.Add(role);? Roles is a collection, so it's the only way to add, isn't it?

Comment: There's a good explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx. Also, you will have less grief if your repositories share a context - look at adding a unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

As Colin pointed out, it is a Context issue. The UserRepository was not aware of the new Role that was inserted in the db.